# Unhandled Exception Error in asp.net linking with vb.net classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, transactions

I have migrated the VB6 DLL to VB.Net components which will interact with front end Asp.net (Asp code). Currently the DLL and Asp.net application is deployed in Windows server 2012 64bit platform. The instance of the DLL will work correctly in one ASPX page but when the page transit to another page. the new instance of the object in the new page is giving unhandled exception error.

The stack trace of the error is as follows.

**System error.**

```
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.EnterpriseServices.Thunk.Proxy.CoCreateObject(Type serverType, Boolean bQuerySCInfo, Boolean& bIsAnotherProcess, String& uri)
   at System.EnterpriseServices.ServicedComponentProxyAttribute.CreateInstance(Type serverType)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.IsCurrentContextOK(RuntimeType serverType, Object[] props, Boolean bNewObj)
   at ASP.logincheck_aspx.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in I:\Rafiq\29-10-2013\Source Code Esmart Application\LoginCheck.aspx:line 42
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: what's the exception message...

Comment: Just to expand on what Ton said...the stack trace tells you where the exception is being thrown, but it doesn't tell us what the exception actually is. You need to provide the Message of the Exception.